# Helm can't find chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I've published my chart to chartmuseum. And yes, I've ran "helm repo update".

```
$ helm search chartmuseum/
NAME                        CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION            
chartmuseum/whoami          1-master                    A Helm chart for whoami
chartmuseum/whoami-master   0.0.1-SNAPSHOT              A Helm chart for whoami
chartmuseum/whoami-release  0.0.1-SNAPSHOT              A Helm chart for whoami
```

But when I try to find it...

```
$ helm install chartmuseum/whoami-release
Error: failed to download "chartmuseum/whoami-release" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

Anyone got a clue about what I do wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/helm/chartmuseum/issues/129 ? Could be related to the versions not being semantic.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion. But I just found out that chartmuseum/whoami works. So I doubt that's the case.

Comment: @RyanDawson Turned out you where spot on! helm --debug install chartmuseum/whoami-release --version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT - Works! If you care to post an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Helm expects semantic versions in order to use the latest one by not explicitly specifying a version in the install command - https://github.com/helm/chartmuseum/issues/129

As you point out in the comments, it does retrieve if you specify the specific version